# session[:user_id] is null when accessing it through API in Rails 7

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm trying to check if the user is logged in by checking if the `session[:user_id]` is set. And I have this session create method in Rails 7:

```
 def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if @user&.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      if @user.activated?

        reset_session

        session[:user_id] = @user.id 
        session[:session_token] = @user.session_token 
       
        render json: {
          user: @user,
          session_token: session[:session_token],
          session_user_id: session[:user_id],
      }
    
  end
```

Then I have the status method to check if the session is set:

```
def status 
  
      render json: { 
        session: session[:user_id],
        
    }
    
  end
```

But when I print the JSON file through this code:

```
 async function login_status() {
    const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/login_status';
    const outputElement = document.getElementById('output');


fetch(apiUrl)
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      if (response.status === 404) {
        throw new Error('Data not found');
      } else if (response.status === 500) {
        throw new Error('Server error');
      } else {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    outputElement.textContent = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
  }
```

I get this :

> { "session": null }

**config/application.rb** have this

```
 config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_interslice_session'
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
    config.middleware.use config.session_store, config.session_options
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
```

I don't know why Rails isn't retrieving the `session[:user_id]` value. Although when I create a user, it does print the `session[:user_id]` value.

**Updates**

Generated access tokens through GET to check if a user is logged in, but where do I store the access tokens? if I store each user's access token in a cookie after logging in, and then use the cookie for each request, is that safe?

```
curl -v -X GET http://localhost:3000/api-keys -H "Authorization: Bearer b5d1dc4641bf5a1fcc7e591723899a62"
```

Comment: An API does not use a session- you need to supply the access token with every request

Comment: @dbugger how do I check if the user is logged in through access tokens?

Comment: @dbugger okay thanks, I was able to generate access tokens, do I store them in cookies in the client side for each logged in user? is that safe? can you please check the updates in the post